# Google Meet share screen black after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, google-meet, ubuntu-22.04

I was using Ubuntu 20.04 and everything was working just fine.

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (deleted everything, a fresh installation) and everything is OK except Google Meet's share screen.

I can join meetings, share my webcam, and send & receive audio & video.

But when I want to share my screen, it shows a black screen.

How can I fix this? Nothing has changed in my laptop hardware.

Answer (score 15):

The solution is pretty simple, Step by step guide to fix screen sharing on Ubuntu 22.04.

Step 1: Check the Default Display Feature
To check the current Ubuntu display, run the following command.

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

If your system is Ubuntu 22.04, its display session is Wayland. Now you have to disable Wayland and enable “Xorg”(x11)

Step 2: Enable “Xorg” and disable “Wayland”
Open gdm3 directory to edit the “custom.conf” file by the following command.

```bash
sudo vi /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Uncomment the following line.

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Step 3: Reboot the system
Now reboot or restart your system to apply the changes. After rebooting you can share your screen on zoom, ms team, etc.

You can confirm the changes by running the following command again.

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

If you correctly change the conf file, it will show you display x11.

Comment: You can simply switch to an Xorg session at the login screen.

Comment: Then my second monitor is black after reboot...

Comment: xorg is playing very badly with the multi-display on ubuntu 21+.. also, enabling wayland doesn't consistently fix the issue, you will get a better share options screen, with the options visible and not black, but the recipient isn't always able to see it.

Answer (score 9):

Just type at chrome address bar...

```
chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer
```

And enable the first entry

Wayland suits best for most users. So, no Wayland give up is necessary.

Comment: this is the best solution, the other option which is to xorg is not stable

Answer (score 1):

I was resolved by going to `chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer` and changing the value from `Default` to `Enabled`.

then

Search for the **file.conf** in **/etc/gdm3/** in my case, Ubuntu 22.04, it's **custom.conf**

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

uncomment the line

`#WaylandEnable=false` to be `WaylandEnable=false`

then `reboot`

"*uncommenting that line will use the Xorg display manager instead of Wayland* "

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just setting chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer to "Enabled" resolved my black screen in Brave browser on Ubuntu 22.04 with a Logitech usb webcam. I did not have to switch back to X11 as the display manager.